# chmod command run within inotifywait doesn't work

Tags: centos, chmod, inotify

I have the following bash script (which is saved as `~/fix-perms.sh`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
inotifywait -d -r -e close_write -o /dev/stdout ~/testdir |
while read path event file; do
    sudo chown user:group "$path$file"
    if [ -d "$file" ]; then
        sudo chmod 750 "$path"
        echo "Created directory '$path' with 750 permissions"
    else
        sudo chmod 640 "$path$file"
        echo "Created file '$path$file' with 640 permissions"
    fi
done
```

I think the intended purpose of this script is obvious, but running it in my `.bashrc` fails to set the group permissions properly, as demonstrated below:

```
# In .bashrc
~/fix-perms.sh &

# In bash session
user@CentOS8:~/testdir$ ls -lha
drwxr-x---   8 user group 4.0K Jun 18 13:06 .
drwxr-x---   8 user group 4.0K Jun 18 11:45 ..
drwxr-x---  12 user group 4.0K Jun 15 21:23 somedir
-rw-r-----   1 user group  316 Jun 15 23:23 somefile
-rw-r-----   1 user group 1.1K Jun 15 21:24 someotherfile
user@CentOS8:~/testdir$ mkdir subdir
user@CentOS8:~/testdir$ ls -lha
drwxr-x---   8 user group 4.0K Jun 18 13:06 .
drwxr-x---   8 user group 4.0K Jun 18 11:45 ..
drwxr-x---  12 user group 4.0K Jun 15 21:23 somedir
-rw-r-----   1 user group  316 Jun 15 23:23 somefile
-rw-r-----   1 user group 1.1K Jun 15 21:24 someotherfile
drwx------  12 user group 4.0K Jun 15 21:23 subdir
```

As you can see, the `subdir` directory is created and given the correct ownership, but the `chmod` command is failing without error for some reason. So what am I doing wrong? MTIA! :-)

EDIT: I have confirmed that `inotifywait` is watching the directory by adding some echo statements to the script, the output of which is now shown in the terminal whenever I add a file or folder to `~/testdir`. I have also changed the event from `create` to `close_write` in the hope that this may better handle my use case.

Comment: `~user/testdir` is probably not below `/var/www/medicnet`, is it? Furthermore you don't have the option `--monitor`. Is `inotifywait` running at all yet when you execute `mkdir`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part...`/var/www/medicnet` is the name of the "real" folder that I'm watching, but when copying output from my terminal and pasting it into the post, I replaced all instances of that string with `~/testdir` for illustration purposes. This would have been fine if I had simply remembered to do the same with the `~/fix-perms.sh` script! I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Why would you use `"$path$file"` with `chown`/`chmod`, but not inside the `[ -d  ... ]` test? Also, who or what is a MTIA?

Comment: @muru The whole point of the `[ -d ... ]` test is to determine whether the thing created is a file or directory. If you can suggest a better way to do so, I'm all ears. And MTIA stands for **M**any **T**hanks **I**n **A**dvance :-)

Comment: Presumably the whole point of using `"$path$file"` was to refer to the file where it is, not wherever your script runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@muru's comment above got me thinking about how I was testing what's being created, and made me realise that I was being very silly. The following code in `~/fix-perms.sh` works nicely:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

inotifywait -dr -e create -o /dev/stdout ~/testdir |
while read path event file; do
    sudo chown user:group "$path$file"
    if [[ $event == *"ISDIR" ]]; then
        sudo chmod 750 "$path$file"
    else
        sudo chmod 640 "$path$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: `--monitor` is still missing so that this will work for the first created object only.

Comment: @HaukeLaging According to [the manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait), `-d` does the same thing as `-m` but in the background...or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: Indeed, sorry for that.